# img and trainData do not overlap when using sperclass in R

Tags: r

I am working on supervised classification using R. I have GeoTiff (`icc_m2_clipped.tif`) clipped to some extent as below and vector train data (`train_ICC.shp`). I have changed by first transforming to same projection system, and reprojected to same crs (`"+proj=utm +zone=35 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"`).

I am not winning when I try to classify the image. I get an error `"img and trainData do not overlap"`. I notice that all train polygons during creation lie within the space of the GeoTiff. Where I am I missing it? Please help.
Also note that I am a newbie in R.

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
library(RStoolbox)
```

[C:\Users\CIFORRO-96M75\Documents\stack_question](https://C:%5CUsers%5CCIFORRO-96M75%5CDocuments%5Cstack_question)

```
ICC_m2_clip<- brick("ICC_m2_clipped.tif")
train_ICC<- readOGR("ICC_train.shp", "ICC_train", verbose = T)

#Change projection of train to that of tiff

spTransform(train_ICC, CRS(ICC_m2_clip))
proj4string(train_ICC)<- crs(ICC_m2_clip)


 img_classified<- superClass(, trainData = train_ICC, responseCol = "id",nSamples = 1000, trainPartition = 0.8, model = "rf", kfold = 5, mode = "classification", predict = TRUE )


Error in superClass(ICC_m2_clip, trainData = train_ICC, responseCol = "id", img and trainData do not overlap
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is, in fact, your exact code, you are not assigning `spTransform(train_ICC, CRS(ICC_m2_clip))` to a object (existing or new). It looks like you are running the function and then assigning the projection string back to the original non-transformed object.

I imagine that simply modifying your code to overwrite the original vector sp object will fix your issue (you do not need to assign an proj4string afterwards).

```
train_ICC <- spTransform(train_ICC, proj4string(ICC_m2_clip))
```

Then check overlay

```
extent(train_ICC)
extent(ICC_m2_clip)

plot(ICC_m2_clip[[1]])
  plot(train_ICC, add=TRUE)
```

Comment: I did run the code above and now got  `Error in !is.na(projargs) && !nzchar(projargs) : 
  invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'`

Comment: Try changing `CRS(ICC_m2_clip)` to `proj4string(ICC_m2_clip)`

Comment: Did you mean `train_ICC_2<- spTransform(train_ICC, proj4string(ICC_m2_clip))
`?    I am still getting the same `Error in superClass(ICC_m2_clip, trainData = train_ICC_2, responseCol = "id",  : 
  img and trainData do not overlap`  . The projection and CRS seems to be same for both Geotiff `ICC_m2_clipp` and vector train `tra_ICC` when I change to the code suggested above .

Comment: In your call to `superClass` you have the first argument as a comma. Perhapse it should be ICC_m2_clip. I am surprised that you are not getting an empty argument error before any reported error from the function.

Comment: the "." in place of comma seems not to work. `icc_classified<- superClass(ICC_m2_clip. trainData = train_ICC_2, responseCol = "id",nSamples = 1000, trainPartition = 0.8, model = "rf", kfold = 5, mode = "classification", predict = TRUE )
Error: unexpected symbol in "icc_classified<- superClass(ICC_m2_clip. trainData"`

Comment: I am still struggling around this. I tried to check also for the merged tiff `ICC_m2_clip` which was later clipped to extent `train_ICC.shp`. The merged and clipped `ICC_m2_clip` shows for some reason that it does not overlap. I tried this code `if(!gIntersects(as(extent(ICC_m2_clip),"SpatialPolygons"), as(extent(train_ICC_2),"SpatialPolygons"))) 
+   stop("img and trainData do not overlap")
Error: img and trainData do not overlap`

Comment: Please post your data so that it is accessible. If you cropped the raster to the shapefile why are you reprojecting it?

Comment: I am not too sure how I can post the data but I created a hyperlink [C:\Users\CIFORRO-96M75\Documents\stack_question] . Can you access it?

Comment: That is an invalid hyperlink. For purposes like this you can always share data. Just invalidate the attributes (ie., strip the vector attributes and replace with generic ID's and assign nonsence values to the rasters). For vectors just use `x@data <- data.frame(ID=1:nrow(x), y=rep(1,nrow(x))` and for rasters use something like `r[!is.na(r)] <- 1` and write out results to disk in the same format you are using for your real data.